# How to get bullet points and product images with MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

How to get Product description, images and bullet points for specific ASIN/SKU with MWS API. I tried with MWS product api, But it is giving only minimum data. Below endpoints i tried to get product details. Can any one help to get my required details?

```
ListMatchingProducts
GetMatchingProduct
GetMatchingProductForId
```

http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/ProductsAPI_Response.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Not available on MWS API. You would need Product Advertising API.

Comment: Can you give sample with Product Advertising API?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html